# Sombreado de una caja en flutter

Tags: flutter, box-shadow

Tengo un widget al cual le quiero sombrear solo la parte de abajo , pero el codigo aun aceptandomelo nose me ve visualmente y nose donde esta el error , debajo de el hay otro widget pegado nose si sera eso...es una appbar y debajo un container conun icono y texto . Gracias un saludo.

```
Widget renderAppBar(){

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 130,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color:Colors.cyan,
          boxShadow: [
            new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
              offset: new Offset(0.0, 20.0),
              blurRadius: 20.0,
        ),
         ],
        ),

        child: Row( 
          children: <Widget> [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 25,
              top: 45
              ),
              child: Text('Inicio',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize:25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              ),
              ),
            )
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Si usas Column/ListView y tienes un widget debajo de ese probablemente esté tapando la sombra, podrías agregarle un padding a tu renderAppBar widget o usar Stack, podrías agregar más código y/o un screenshot de como se ve actualmente

Comment: Tenias razon Diego no se me habia ocurrido meterle un padding al renderAppBar  en el column del Scaffold donde llamo al widge para que no se solape con el widget siguiente , ya esta solucionado muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Ostras el problema es que no me lo degrada me hace como una linea de color no va de mas negro a mas clarito como en la foto de abajo

Comment: Usa Colors.black45 o similar.

Comment: black12 es el que mas se asemeja pero no es un degradado creo que es con lineargradient pero haber donde lo meto xd

Comment: Revisa las otras propiedades de Shadow y juega con ellas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Tu código muestra el contenedor con el sombreado]

Tu código está bien el tema es que el Widget que pones abajo está tapando la sombra. Lo que podes hacer si estas poniendo todo en el body es usar el Stack y poner primero la parte que va abajo y luego el appbar que creaste para que quede arriba junto con la sombra. Sino agregale un padding al de abajo para que deje lugar a la sombra. Espero que mi respuesta te ayude.

Comment: Si si exacto no me e dado cuenta error tonto ejejejeje lo tapaba el toro como dices muchas gracias!!